# Mount remote FTP server on windows machine

Tags: winapi, mfc

I want to write code in vc++ to mount remote machine (with FTP server running on remote machine)  as local drive on my PC.

Please suggest the API which can mount the remote machine using ftp protocol, like "WNetAddConnection2" uses smb protocol.

Or please suggest something regarding the same.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/158667)

Answer (score 0):

Manually it can be done through "Add network drive" option in my computer in windows, u need to fill ftp address of server and it will be mounted as local drive.

Comment: Yes i am able to do it manually,,, but i want to know to code it in vc++. Please suggest API.

Answer (score 0):

*Hello.
It is not trivial task.
Mounting remote machine as disk required many APIs.
For FTP may use FTP families of WinInet functions, for Shell is required knowledge of pidls and many related shell functions.*

Rather use MSIEFTP.DLL/Microsoft Internet Explorer FTP Folder Shell Extension. :-)